# Cleared and Unformatted partitions in GParted

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, gparted

I was formatting my drive and found a partition system named ***cleared and unformatted***. What are those partitions and why they are in **GParted** app ?

Answer (score 0):

If GParted indicates a partition is cleared and unformatted then GParted does not see any file system signatures on the partition.  Please note that it is always possible that the partition contains a file system that is not recognized by GParted.

Comment: Nope, here what I am saying is that I got an option (cleared and unformatted) in GParted.

Comment: The GParted menu option **Partition -> Format to -> cleared** will erase file system signatures from the partition.  It does this by overwriting with zeros the known file system signature locations in the partition.

Answer (score 0):

paraphrased from Super User 2015.12 https://superuser.com/questions/706624/cleared-vs-unformatted-partition-in-gparted

asked by nday 2014.01.24:

I am running a database-like application that writes and reads data directly to and from a raw block device. I would like to create a new partition for this purpose, and I am using GParted. I've successfully shrank my regular linux partition, and I can now see the free space listed as "unallocated". Gparted allows you to choose to format this space to be "unformatted" or "cleared". I don't understand their difference.

In the GParted help/manual, it says this:

- cleared can be used to clear any existing file system signatures and ensure that the partition is recognised as empty.
- unformatted can be used to just create a partition without writing a file system.

I couldn't find any elaboration on their difference. Can someone explain it? Also, is there any impact on the reliability of the partition, or on performance when writing and reading from it? Is one of them better-suited for my purpose? Are there any implications to just leaving the partition "unallocated" as it currently is? Thanks!

answered in most part by JdeBP 2014.01.24, improved by user29020 2014.07.12:

These two options are unfortunately listed along with the others that act in a different manner. The other options are all filesystem formats, where the new partition is created with the selected format. The two options of interest are essentially the two null options.

- If one leaves a partition "unformatted" then no attempt to write filesystem data structures to it is made at all. But it might have them already, by accident or by design.
- If one "clears" a partition, then the various signatures in well-known places that operating systems use to detect filesystem types ( http://jdebp.eu./FGA/determining-filesystem-type.html ) are wiped.

So, rather ironically, clearing a partition will give one the guarantee of it being unformatted as a result, whereas an unformatted partition may remain formatted as before.